# Nest imports under parent class selector

Tags: css, fonts, sass, font-face

I would like to restrict my SCSS within a certain module and in theory I would like to nest my imports within a parent level class

HTML

```
<body class="grandfather">
...
</body>
```

app.scss

```
@charset 'UTF-8';

@import 'scss/_vendors/__vendors-dir';
@import 'scss/_abstracts/__abstracts-dir';
@import 'scss/_base/__base-dir';
@import 'scss/_components/__components-dir';
@import 'scss/_layouts/__layouts-dir';
@import 'scss/_pages/__pages-dir';
@import 'scss/_themes/__themes-dir';
```

I tried to nest the imports under the class `.grandfather`

app.scss (breaks @fontface and @keyframes and maybe more)

```
@charset 'UTF-8';

.grandfather {
    @import 'scss/_vendors/__vendors-dir';
    @import 'scss/_abstracts/__abstracts-dir';
    @import 'scss/_base/__base-dir';
    @import 'scss/_components/__components-dir';
    @import 'scss/_layouts/__layouts-dir';
    @import 'scss/_pages/__pages-dir';
    @import 'scss/_themes/__themes-dir';
}
```

Is there any solution in .scss to solve this problem?

Comment: [Check the Nested @import Directive part of this page](http://vanseodesign.com/css/sass-the-import-directive)